# How do I get rid of "FALSE" when using this excell formula?

Tags: excel-formula

When using this formula I get the correct answer.  However, when I copy this down to the next blank cell I get "FALSE" but I want it to be blank.  Not "BLANK" but empty.

=IF(ISNUMBER(E5),IF(D5="LONG",((H5*I5)+(K5*L5))-(E5*F5),IF(D5="SHORT",(E5*F5)-((H5*I5)+(K5*L5)))))

I have also tried these formulas with the same results:

=IF(D17="LONG",((H17*I17)+(K17*L17))-(E17*F17),IF(D17="SHORT",(E17*F17)-((H17*I17)+(K17*L17,””))))

=IF(D18="LONG",((H18*I18)+(K18*L18))-(E18*F18),IF(D18="SHORT",(E18*F18)-((H18*I18)+(K18*L18),"")))

Comment: You have put the ,"" instead ), but I don't understand e.g. K18L18 wath's mean, is a defined range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the FALSE parameters, without this, considering the result of conditions, return FALSE. Try this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(E5),IF(D5="LONG",((H5I5)+(K5L5))-(E5F5),IF(D5="SHORT",(E5F5)-((H5I5)+(K5L5)),"")),"")
```

Comment: When I use that formula I get #NAME? instead of FALSE.

Comment: I think that refer is wrong: E5F5, but I've copied your formula
Wath's this ranges?

Comment: Using E5*F5 makes the formula work.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

=IF(ISNUMBER(E5),IF(D5="LONG",((H5I5)+(K5L5))-(E5F5),IF(D5="SHORT",(E5F5)-((H5I5)+(K5L5)))), "")

I've just put blank quotes as output when the condition is FALSE.

Comment: When I use this formula I get #NAME? instead of FALSE.